# Cant see Facebook conversion pixels bveing reported for Android app

Tags: android, facebook

In FBs SDK there is a class "InsightsLogger" and in it function logConversionPixel

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/InsightsLogger/

And in FBs help section, they state you need to configure each pixel for the ad

> In the "Campaign, Pricing, and Schedule" section, you will see an option to Track conversions on my website for this ad

So i created the pixels and added the code in my app, and i can see that the pixels are "Active.

But for some reason i am not seeing this option for my mobile install ads. Are conversion pixel open for Android?

And non of them getting reported in the ads.

1. is this due to the missing configuration?
2. is conversion pixels open for android app installs?

Comment: hey I'm having the same issue, did you sort it out?

Comment: Unfortunately no. 
I am currently hooking on the undocumented "apps.facebook.com" referrer to track conversion.
http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22571628-Android-app-installs-from-Facebook-Organic

Comment: I can see now that the pixels are also being reported in the Insights -> Event Detail... not much help per ad but at least some thing

Comment: interesting! I'm not sure but I think my issue was quite different. Facebook ads were not reporting anything on my android app and fb support told me it was a problem of conversion pixels. It was actually due to this missing line: com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync(context, YOUR_APP_ID); https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/

Comment: FB added in its Android SDK V3.5 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/AppEventsLogger and deprecated InsightsLogger. Using the new class will "also be used for ads conversion tracking, optimization, and other ads related targeting in the future."

Answer (score 0):

For FB Android SDK 3.5, you will be able to measure total installs and total times your app is launched daily by adding the following to onResume() of each Activity in your app:

```
com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(context, YOUR_APP_ID);
```